# Why do these two Gstreamer pipelines work fine separately, but fail when tee'd from the source?

Tags: gstreamer

The below pipeline works fine if I either send it to UDP, or if I sent to a file. When I connect them with a tee, the pipeline does nothing (no data sent to file or UDP port). No errors are printed, however, when I hit CTRL-C the pipeline waits for EOL shutdown and I have to CTRL-C again.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
  rtspsrc location='rtsp://userid:pwd@10.0.0.1:554' latency=100 ! \
  tee name=t ! \
    queue ! \
    rtph264depay ! \
    h264parse ! \
    mp4mux ! \
    filesink location=tee.mp4 \
  t. ! \
    queue ! \
    udpsink host=192.168.1.140 port=5000
```

This works fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
  rtspsrc location='rtsp://userid:pwd@10.0.0.1:554' latency=100 ! \
  rtph264depay ! \
  h264parse ! \
  mp4mux ! \
  filesink location=tee.mp4
```

and this works fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
  rtspsrc location='rtsp://userid:pwd@10.0.0.1:554' latency=100 ! \
  udpsink host=192.168.1.140 port=5000
```

But not teed.

Comment: The complete log output would be helpful still. Can you try increasing the queue sizes?

Comment: I thought default max-size-buffers was 200, since that was what gst-inspect (and all of the documentation) reports. But when I add `max-size-buffers=200` to both queues, it now works. I don't know why those numbers wouldn't match. Very odd, but thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: It should be 200. Also note there are three different max limits. It could be in some cases 200 is not enough (assuming this is a live source).

Comment: I know, weird, right? It is a live camera, but the conditions were the same with and without explicitly setting `queue max-size-buffers=200`, so I can rule out extra activity causing increased bitrate. The GST_DEBUG log did not provide any clues. It works now so if you want to make your comment and answer I'll check it.